# Why do packages have tons of Referenced Packages - often with warnings?

Tags: eclipse, error, package.xml

When creating new packages and importing them into the Force.com IDE I recently saw many Referenced Packages which seem to have no connection to my app at all.

[image]

I would ignore this if not sometimes it woul prevent me from doing a "Refresh from Server" with a:

> Refresh error: Metadata API received improper input. Please ensure
>   file name and capitalization is correct. Load of metadata from db
>   failed for metadata of type:ConnectedApp and file
>   name:09HF000000003lw. package.xml /TravelExp Trunk/Referenced
>   Packages/Salesforce Connected Apps    line 1  Force.com retrieve problem

Answer (score 5):

Wow this is strange! I've never seen this before either, mainly because i create my project in such a way to avoid downloading this, see below. Regarding what this is, it is most interesting, more so the contents of them, typically these are contents of managed packages in your org. But looking through some in my org reveals some very interesting **package.xml** and **.module** files?

I've searched the **Metadata API** and **Metadata WSDL** for references and find none, so maybe they are some local Eclipse plugin concept, not sure. It may be possible to dig deeper by tracing the requests Eclipse makes to Salesforce.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Avoiding Reference Packages Download in Eclipse**

What i do know is i generally avoid the overhead of the **Referenced Packages** by select None when creating the Force.com project and prompted for the initial project contents, then once the project is created, right click and selected Add/Remove Metadata Components... to add/subscribe to what I need to work on the contents of the org. This results in an empty Referenced Packages node in the project explorer.

Comment: I always connect Eclipse to Packages as this will add any new artefact directly to the package.

Comment: Ah I see, yes that is a benefit, though typically most related artefacts get automatically added regardless, e.g adding a new dependent class or custom field etc. But yes, if you value this feature then looks like you have to accept for now until we get further explanation from Salesforce this overhead. Sorry. :-(

Comment: I just tried this, and it doesn't seem to work for me.  Creating the blank project adds 'standalone="yes"' to the package.xml, but when I try to sync the project after adding my meta components, it removes this, and downloads the referenced package again. (Eclipse Kepler 4.3 and   Force.com IDE 33.0.0.201504091124)